# How to embed a link with a picture to Facebook using the Graph API?

Tags: ios

I upload a picture to facebook using Graph api, when i click the picture it automatically navigate to default "link" url. But, i need it has to navigate to another new url embed with picture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It will post Image with description  and on click will redirect to Link you provide.

```
        NSMutableDictionary *params = 
        [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"Post Feed", @"name",
         @"Feed is Awesome.", @"caption",
         @"Check out how to use Facebook.", @"description",
         @"http://www.kamleshwar.com/blog",@"link",
         @"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/zqUW68itCec/default.jpg", @"picture",
         nil];  

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"feed"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```